# Python: How to update a value in Google BigQuery in less than 40 seconds?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a table in `Google BigQuery` that I access and modify in Python using the `pandas` functions `read_gbq` and `to_gbq`. The problem is that appending 100,000 lines takes about 150 seconds while appending 1 line takes about 40 seconds. I would like to update a value in the table rather than append a line, is there a way to update a value in the table using python that is very fast, or faster than 40 seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you can do so using `pandas` but you sure can using `google-cloud` library.

You could just install it (`pip install --upgrade google-cloud`) and run it like:

```
import uuid
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path_to_json_credentials.json'
from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

bq_client = Client()

job_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
query = """UPDATE `dataset.table` SET field_1 = '3' WHERE field_2 = '1'"""
job = bq_client.run_async_query(query=query, job_name=job_id)
job.use_legacy_sql = False
job.begin()
```

Here this operation is taking 2s on average.

As a side note, it's important to keep in mind the [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#datasettableupdates) related to DML operations in BQ, that is, know when it's appropriate to use them and if they fit your needs well.

Comment: Do you think I am interpreting [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#quotas) correctly in saying as I can only update 96 values per day in a single table? So if I have 8 columns and 100,000,000 rows, I can only update 96 of those 800,000,000 values per day?

Comment: You can run 96 UPDATE operations per day per table. You can UPDATE any amount of rows given your `WHERE` clause (for instance, `where user_id=2` will take all rows with user_id 2 and update them, even if it selects thousands of rows).

Comment: Thanks for helping me with that. In my specific case, I will have a separate table where each row represents a job to be executed, and there will be about 250,000 jobs (250,000 rows). One of the fields in each row is "datetime_of_last_update" that I wanted to `update` when the job is successfully executed by `update`-ing the value to the datetime that the job finished. Would you agree that due to the 96 UPDATE operations per day I would not be able to update the datetimes one by one be 250,000 jobs > the 96 quota?

Comment: yeah, I agree. BigQuery is not designed to handle data being constantly updated but rather it's more a DW solution. Maybe you could run some tests with [datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/) and see if it works well for you in this case.

Comment: Starting from March 2020, DML without limits, now in BigQuery - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

With the `google-cloud` library update, you can now do as follows .

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project)

query = 
"""
(
UPDATE `dataset.table` SET field_1 = '3' WHERE field_2 = '1
)
"""

job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(use_legacy_sql=False)

query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)

print("Updated query")

for row in query_job:

    print(row)
```